# How to revoke MySQL user privileges for one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, privileges

When I have granted privileges to a user for some specific tables:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON table1.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON table2.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

How do I revoke the privileges for this user, just for `table1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google is your friend!
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html

Syntax:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON table1.* FROM 'user1'@'localhost';
```

---

To further explain this answer - I'll teach how to fish (rather than just give you a fish).

The MySQL documentation can look confusing at first - the "syntax" for `REVOKE` looks like this:

```
REVOKE
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    FROM user [, user] ...

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION
    FROM user [, user] ...

REVOKE PROXY ON user
    FROM user [, user] ...
```

It means there are 3 "ways" of calling it:

1. `REVOKE priv_type ...`
2. `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT ...`
3. `REVOKE PROXY ON ...`

These three are separated by the blank lines in the MySQL doc page.

For each of these, there are "optional" parameters/settings/values.  These are denoted by the square brackets, for example:

```
REVOKE priv_type [(column_list)] ...
```

The `(column_list)` is optional.  You can supply it, but you don't *have* to.

(**Updated note, Dec 2019:**

The `priv_type` is what specifically lets us know we can specify `ALL PRIVILEGES`; for we are told in the documentation linked above:

> For details on the levels at which privileges exist, the permissible `priv_type`, `priv_level`, and `object_type values`, and the syntax for specifying users and passwords, see Section 13.7.1.4, “`GRANT` Statement”.

Section 13.7.1.4 states this:

> **Privileges Supported by MySQL**
>
> The following table summarizes the permissible priv_type privilege types that can be specified for the `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements, and the levels at which each privilege can be granted.
>
> - `ALL [PRIVILEGES]` Grant all privileges at specified access

**End update.**)

Similarly you can chain these together - they've indented the next line to indicate this (and used `...` to show you can continue repeating):

```
priv_type [(column_list)]
  [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...    <-- indented, and note the "..."
```

More complicated examples exist in the MySQL documentation - like for `CREATE TABLE` you have lists of optional flags:

```
[COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
```

This `{x|y|z}` syntax indicates you **must** specify one of them (the `{...}` is non-optional, the `[...]` means everything inside is optional - so if you specify `COLUMN_FORMAT`, one of the three following flags is **required**), the pipes (`|`) indicate you can only specify **one** of the list (`FIXED` / `DYNAMIC` / `DEFAULT`).

---

One final thing to say - be very aware of the MySQL documentation *version*.  It's stated in several places on the website - personally I just look at the URL:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html
```

Note it says `5.7` in it.  This means the documentation you're reading *may* not be applicable to any version other than MySQL 5.7.  That's bitten me a lot of times ... usually when I'm under the gun trying to fix something in a panic!  Always double-check it.

Comment: Extended answer to help explain how the MySQL documentation is formatted.

Comment: The example answer is especially helpful here, since the documentation does not make it clear that `REVOKE ALL` can be used in conjunction with an `ON` filter. Thank you.

Comment: Added clarification as to how we know `ALL PRIVILEGES` works.

Answer (score 3):

@Nadeem Taj. You are not correct. If you previously granted all privileges on. *.*

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES on Tblname.*`  treats Tblname as a schema name.

Proof:

```
mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[amp]> create user 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[mysql]> grant all privileges on  *.* to 'myuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[mysql]> create database specialdb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[mysql]> use specialdb;
Database changed
mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[specialdb]> create table tbl1(col1 int primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[mysql]> insert into specialdb.tbl1(col1) values(1),(2),(3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[specialdb]> REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON tbl1.* FROM 'myuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql<root@127.0.0.1:[specialdb]> exit
Bye

$ mysql mysql  -umyuser -p
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 44
Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql<myuser@127.0.0.1:[mysql]> select * from specialdb.tbl1;
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql<myuser@127.0.0.1:[mysql]>
```

Comment: Who are you referring to in the answer ? The person is not in questions or answers section

Comment: @mishsx I was referring to the person that "hid" my previous response. This post is a proof that when someone has been granted all privileges in all schemas the accepted answer is not valid. In addition MySQL does supports partial revokes but they work at schema-level only.