# Get One Normal Table and Counts From Another Table In One SQL Query (JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need a SQL query which gives content of one table and count of second table. I tried, could not.

I have a "comments" table. And in the another table named "likings", there are numbers of likes of comments.

In my algorithm, in the "likings" table, there are a column named "`likeType`", if it is "`1`" that means a like, otherwise (if it is "`0`") means a dislike. I need to bring comment from "`comments`" table, counts of `likeType=1` and `likeType=0` from "`likings`" table in one query.

Here is my best attempt for that, which didn't work:

---

PHP side:


   `$getFirst8Comments = "SELECT
                            episodecomments.cmtID,
                            episodecomments.cmtConEpisode,
                            episodecomments.cmtOwner,
                            episodecomments.cmtDate,
                            episodecomments.cmtContent,
                            episodecomments.cmtSpoiler,
                            SUM(IF(episodecommentsliking.liType='1', 1, 0)) AS likes,
                            SUM(IF(episodecommentsliking.liType='0', 1, 0)) AS dislikes
                        FROM episodecomments
                        LEFT JOIN episodecommentsliking
                        ON episodecomments.cmtID = episodecommentsliking.liCmtID
                        GROUP BY
                            episodecomments.cmtID,
                            episodecomments.cmtConEpisode,
                            episodecomments.cmtOwner,
                            episodecomments.cmtDate,
                            episodecomments.cmtContent,
                            episodecomments.cmtSpoiler
                        WHERE episodecomments.cmtConEpisode='$epID'
                        ORDER BY episodecomments.cmtID
                        DESC LIMIT 8";

   while ($getF8C = mysqli_fetch_array($getFirst8Comments))
   {
      echo "Something coming through-<br>";
   }`

Error pops out: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in J:\file.php on line 3484 (error in variable $getFirst8Comments)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your query attempt(s).

Comment: Read this [StackOverflow | How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or that [Spaghetti DBA | How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/), or even better: read both!

Comment: Sorry, updated. I'm kind of new here. @jarih

Comment: this is better. See? now your question is not downvoted anymore ;-)

Comment: Yes seems like it is, but you can be a bit humble, that doesn't hurt anyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `COUNT` in that fashion.  You'll also need to inform it what to `GROUP BY` for those aggregate (sum) functions.

Try using `SUM` instead:  (`COUNT` would work if you're counting `NULL` vs non-`NULL` values however - see the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html))

```
  SELECT
    comments.cmtID,
    comments.cmtConEpisode,
    comments.cmtOwner,
    comments.cmtDate,
    comments.cmtContent,
    comments.cmtSpoiler,
    SUM(IF(commentsliking.liType='1', 1, 0)) AS likes,
    SUM(IF(commentsliking.liType='0', 1, 0)) AS dislikes
  FROM comments
  INNER JOIN commentsliking
    ON comments.cmtID = commentsliking.liCmtID
  GROUP BY
    comments.cmtID,
    comments.cmtConEpisode,
    comments.cmtOwner,
    comments.cmtDate,
    comments.cmtContent,
    comments.cmtSpoiler
  ORDER BY comments.cmtID
  DESC LIMIT 8
```

---

Also - use "`LEFT JOIN`" if there's the possibility that a comment record will exist with no like data.

---

I've further updated my answer to address the error you've since reported being thrown by the `mysqli_*` commands.

Check the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) for full details on how to correctly use the `mysqli_fetch_array()` function - especially with regards to it requiring a `mysqli_result` type as an argument, as opposed to a `string` [of SQL])

Comment: I'm trying to apply it but it's like there is a syntax error somewhere in the query, according to php. `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result(), string given in $getComments.`. And I double checked the column names, they seem true. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: That's a PHP/MySQL client issue, rather than syntax with the SQL.  You'll need to post a full copy of your code somewhere for me to see what's wrong.

Comment: I can see the issue.  Check the documentation for `mysqli_fetch_array` ( http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php ).  You can see it requires a `mysqli_result` type object passing into it - not a string of SQL.  There's a full example on that PHP documentation page which shows how to connect to the database and perform a query in the manner you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks four your help, but as  a result of my attempts, i learned that 'GROUP BY' must be written after 'WHERE' :D I fixed, and that works. Thank you for your interest again.

Comment: No problem.  You might find useful an answer I gave a while ago on another question - where I explain how to read the MySQL documentation to diagnose problems like should GROUP BY come before or after WHERE etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020387/how-to-revoke-mysql-user-privileges-for-one-table/34020437#34020437